# Data Validation UDF & Implicit intersection operator (@)

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

The basics of the code below are covered in this thread: [Dynamic Data Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319996/dynamic-data-validation)

That code is similar to the code below, but it creates a DV with a dynamic string, which sometimes exceeds the 255-character limit for comma-separated values. I changed it to use a dynamic range instead since the data it looks for is already grouped/sorted.

The @ operator Excel adds to UDFs, was never an issue on the string-based DV UDF, but now the range-based DV UDF returns a #VALUE! error when the worksheet change sub calls the UDF - and if I manually remove the @ then the DV works as expected.

What is also interesting, is by stepping through the code, it seems the UDF stops mid-way on this line `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertWarning, Formula1:="='Tags'!" & RNG.Address` and then restarts on `ElseIf QTY > 1 Then` but then runs past this point without issue on what seems to be a "second" run.

As mentioned on the other thread, Events have been disabled in the worksheet change sub to prevent calling the UDF twice, but for some reason, it still runs twice, well sort of from what I can tell with strategically placed `Debug.Print 1` lines.

Any suggestions on the #VALUE! error and double execution?

```
Option Explicit

Function DDDDL(Variable)

Dim Find As String, List As String
Dim QTY As Integer, Row As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim RNG As Range, Cell As Range

lastrow = Sheets("Tags").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
QTY = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Variable, Sheets("Tags").Range("B3:B" & lastrow), Sheets("Tags").Range("A3:A" & lastrow), 0, 0, 1)

    If QTY = 0 Then
        Application.ThisCell.Validation.Delete
        DDDDL = "Tag not found in DB"

    ElseIf QTY = 1 Then
        Application.ThisCell.Validation.Delete
        DDDDL = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Variable, Sheets("Tags").Range("B3:B" & lastrow), _
        Sheets("Tags").Range("C3:C" & lastrow), "TAG Description NOT found", 0, 1)

    ElseIf QTY > 1 Then
        DDDDL = "Pick From List"
                Row = Worksheets("Tags").Range("B3:B" & lastrow).Find(Variable, , xlValues, xlWhole).Row
            Set RNG = Range("C" & Row & ":C" & (Row + QTY - 1))
                With Application.ThisCell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertWarning, Formula1:="='Tags'!" & RNG.Address
                        .InCellDropdown = True
                        .ErrorTitle = "TAG Description NOT found"
                        .ErrorMessage = "This TAG Description was not found in the Database." & vbCrLf & "Click YES to continue, but remember to register the TAG."
                End With
    End If
End Function
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = Range("K22:K" & lastrow)
    Set rng2 = Range("S22:S" & lastrow)
    Set rng3 = Range("C19:C" & lastrow)
        
        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng1).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12).Validation.Delete
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12) = ""
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"
                End If
        End If

        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng2).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 20).Validation.Delete
                    Cells(Target.Row, 20) = ""
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 20).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"
                End If
        End If
        
        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng3) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng3).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then
                    UpdateTheRibbon
                End If
        End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I should also mention that if Events are disabled and Worksheet_Change doesn't fire, then the UDF works perfectly, but Worksheet_Change hasn't been changed. Think this is why the UDF runs twice as ```Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"``` calls it again

Comment: `Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"` does trigger Worksheet `Change` event. It triggers `Calculate` one (being modified as a formula... I would suggest you to check the code in this (`Calculate`) event.

Comment: Changing the line ```Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"``` to ```Cells(Target.Row, 20).Formula = "=DDDDL(" & Target.Address & ")"``` solved both issues and the implicit operator @ doesn't affect anything as well - just like before. Thanks for the tip on narrowing down the possible cause FaneDuru